# RawData is equal null for jpg images

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to add image to pdf file. I'm using iTextSharp for this.
I have the following code:

```
var imageBanner = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bannerImagePath);
```

The problem in that the `RawData` property is equal `NULL` for `jpg` images, but for `png` is all ok.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read chapter 10 of the book "iText in Action". The `Image` class is abstract. It has different implementations for different image types. Some image types exist in PDF. For instance: a JPG (DCTDecode) can be copied literally into a PDF. File types such as PNG and GIF don't exist in PDF, so they need to be converted to `raw data` first; they are compressed (FlateDecode) later on in the process.

As there's absolutely no need for any 'processing' when dealing with JPGs, no memory is wasted on creating a raw image. It would be bad if `RawData` weren't `null`, hence my question: why is it a problem for you? you should be happy that `RawData` is `null`!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have a code that make image gray. And, I need to get image like `byte[]`.

Comment: OK, I understand, but iText doesn't support conversion of JPG to raw data. Sorry for that...